Estimates for the first coefficient of the Taylor expansion of $\zeta$ around a zero
Let's suppose that $s_0=\frac{1}{2}-\Delta+it$ with $0<\Delta<\frac{1}{2}$ is a simple zeta zero (i.e a zero not on the critical line). Then $1-\overline{s_0}$ is also a zero.
If we take the Taylor expansion of zeta around $s_0$ and $1-\overline{s_0}$  we get :
$\zeta(s)=c_1(s-s_0)+ \textit{higher order terms}$ in a small nbh around $s_0$
$\zeta(s)=c'_1(s-1+\overline{s_0})+ \textit{higher order terms}$ in a small nbh around $1-\overline{s_0}$.
I managed to notice that $\frac{c_1}{c'_1} \geq 1$ based on work of Saidak and Zvengrowski. Are there any better estimates for $\frac{c_1}{c'_1}$, and do they depend on $|s_0|$?

Since
$$c_1=\zeta'(s_0)\qquad\text{and}\qquad c_1'=\zeta'(1-\overline{s_0})=\overline{\zeta'(1-s_0)},$$
the question concerns $|\zeta'(s_0)/\zeta'(1-s_0)|$. The functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ can be expressed as
$$Z(s)=Z(1-s),\qquad \text{where}\qquad Z(s):=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s).$$
Therefore, $Z'(s)=-Z'(1-s)$, and hence by the Leibniz rule for derivatives,
$$\pi^{-s_0/2}\Gamma(s_0/2)\zeta'(s_0)=-\pi^{-1/2+s_0/2}\Gamma(1/2-s_0/2)\zeta'(1-s_0).$$
It follows that
$$\left|\frac{\zeta'(s_0)}{\zeta'(1-s_0)}\right|<\left|\frac{\Gamma(1/2-s_0/2)}{\Gamma(s_0/2)}\right|.$$
For the ratio of $\Gamma$-values on the right-hand side, one can generate an asymptotic expansion with explicit error term by using a suitable version of Stirling's formula.

Thank you very much!
